# Call virtual function after derived class object construction

Tags: c++, constructor, polymorphism

Here is some sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        std::cout << "base" << std::endl;
    }

    A() {
        foo();
    }
};

class B : public A {
    int a;
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "derived" << std::endl;
    }

    B(int a) :
        a(a) {}
};

int main() {
    B o(1);
    return 0;
}
```

I want `foo()` to get called every time some `A` derived object is constructed. I do not want to call `foo()` explicitly in every derived class constructor.

Is there a way to do this in some elegant way?

Comment: To be clear, you want the derived `foo()` overloads to be called, even though that's *not* what happens in your sample program?

Comment: Yes. If overload would take place in my code, then my question is pointless.

Comment: Oops, I mean overrides, not overloads.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way you can call an overridden `foo()` from a base class constructor, no matter what you do.  When the base class constructor is called, the derived class object **has not been constructed yet**, so you cannot call any of its methods or access any of its members.  This is true for virtual functions and regular functions as well.  In a base class constructor, the `this` pointer is pointing at the base class, not the derived class.

Comment: I do not necessary want to call it from the constructor. I want to call it after all derived class object construction(full), but without need to put additional code in derived class.

Comment: @omicronns, sorry, it is impossible to do so.

Comment: @omicronns This is also extremely confusing, you want to call a function from the derived class without adding extra code to the derived class? Surely the implementation of whatever function would be called from the derived class  would result in extra code? Why not just have the derived class call whatever function the base class was going to call?

Answer (score 1):

A potential workaround is to delegate construction to a separate function that clients will have to call instead. Then have that function call foo after construction:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        std::cout << "base" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename T, typename ... Args>
    static T construct(Args ... args)
    {
        T newT{ args... };
        newT.foo();
        return std::move(newT);
    }

protected:
    A() {
        //Construct A
    }
};
class B : public A {
    int a;
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "derived" << std::endl;
    }

    B(int a) :
        a(a) {}
};

int main()
{
    B o = A::construct<B>(1);
    A a = A::construct<A>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you can still do `B o(1);` - so it requires programmer discipline to use the *creator*. But if you have enough discipline to use *creator*, why even bother with it? By the same discipline you can simply call foo() at the call site.

Comment: @SergeyA Yup, it's not perfect. You could make the child class constructors protected as well, but then you'd need friend declarations in all the child classes. Perhaps that's reasonable in this scenario. I still think this is a reasonable solution to the OP's problem.